# create keystore for tomcat using .key ,.ca and .cert file

Tags: tomcat, ssl, openssl, keytool, verisign

I have three file sample.cert, sample.CA,sample.key provided by verisign. I need to create keystore for tomcat.As I searched I cannot use .key file directly to create keystore.

command used by me as below :

```
 pkcs12 -export -in sample.cert -inkey sample.key  -CAfile sample.crt -out sample.p12
```

(I changed sample.CA to sample.crt..)

I use openssl to create sample.p12 file. Then I import sample.p12 to sample.jsk by using keytool.

```
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore samp.p12 -destkeystore sample.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

while I verify certificate it show Intermediate certificate chaining issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just be missing one paramater in the openssl command.  Add "-chain" to the end to see if that fixes things.  Note that if openssl can't establish the chain, the command will fail.

Example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in MYCERT.crt -inkey MYKEY.key -out KEYSTORE.p12 -name "tomcat" -CAfile MY-CA-CERT.crt -caname "myCA" -chain
```

The "-name" and "-caname" parameters give a "friendly name" to each certificate, and are optional.

The documentation for openssl pkcs12 and its various parameters is [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html).

Comment: I also added -chain argument bt it show error "unable to get issuer certificate getting chain"

Comment: Can you post the sample files somewhere so we can verify the chain?

Comment: gtrig actually these sample files are original files.It contain private key.

Comment: If my memory is correct, you can verify the certificate chain with this openssl command:  openssl verify -CAfile cacert.pem mycert.pem.  As indicated, both certs must be in pem format.  You can also verify the private key goes with your cert with the commands on this [page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html#verify).